# Keep the order of list node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am looping through an object (I have also tried it with an array) and building a list of urls. I have tried to enumerate using for...in and to iterate using for but I keep losing the order.

```
 var Model = require('./model');
        var Scraper = require('./scraper');
        var Pages = [];
        function generateUrls(limit) {
          var url = 'http://www.weatheronline.co.uk/SouthAfrica/';
          var urls = [];

          Cities = {
    'Windhoek'  : 'Windhoek',
    'GraaffReinet' : 'GraaffReinet',
    'Queenstown'  : 'Queenstown',
    'Bhisho'  : 'Bhisho',
};
    };

      for (City in Cities) {
        urls.push(url + Cities[City]);
      }
      return urls;
    }
    // store all urls in a global variable  
    Pages = generateUrls();
    function wizard() {
      // if the Pages array is empty, we are Done!!
      if (!Pages.length) {
        return console.log('Done!!!!');
      }
```

How can I keep the order. After I scrape some of the weather data I display a table of the data on a localhost. I use node.js with mongo, express and jade.

Here is the jade code to create the table.

```
doctype html
html
  body
    table(style='width:100%')
      tr
        th City
        th Min
        th Max Day 1
        th Max Day 2
        th Max Day 3

      each city, i in Listings
       tr
        td 
         span= city.city
        td 
         span= city.min
        td 
         span= city.max
        td 
         span= city.maxday2
        td 
         span= city.maxday3
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by losing the order. What is "Listings" in your Jade code? Can't find that in the node.js code.

Comment: What do you mean by losing the order? It is not very clear.

Comment: "Listings" is the Mongo collection. Like Zac Braddy answered the order is arbitrary. You would expect to see Windhoek, Graaf-Reinet, Queenstown, Bhisho. But it returns in a random order.

Comment: So use a normal for loop and an array for your cities. Or go with the way Zac described if you need **Cities** to be an Object.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you read the comments below as well because there is relevant information in them!!**

For in loops don't guarantee that they will iterate over the object in a index 0 to n sort of way. A quote from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) :

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object, in **arbitrary** order.

I recently came up against a similar problem and I resolved it by including an array of strings of the keys in the object which described the order that I wanted to iterate over the object in. So when I wanted to iterate over the object I just iterated over the array using a for loop and then accessed the keys using obj[key].

This has two drawbacks, first I had to write code to keep the obj and the array in sync so when things got added I to the object I needed code to update the array. Also I had to ensure that I included a hasOwnProperty check in the loop to ensure that my array was full of garbage keys.

It might not be the solution you were looking for or one that you can implement in your scenario but it certainly worked for me. Good luck!

[EDIT] Just in case I wasn't clear here is a code example:

```
var obj = { 
    Test1: 1,
    Test3: 3,
    Test2: 2,
    propNames: ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']
};

for(var i = 0; i < obj.propNames.length; i++) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(obj.propNames[i])) continue;

    console.log(obj.propNames[i] + ": " + obj[obj.propNames[i]]);
}

// OUTPUT
// Test1: 1
// Test2: 2
// Test3: 3
```

Comment: The alternative would be to use a normal for loop if you iterate over an array anyways. In his case he states he tried with an array too, but I guess he did the for...in loop there as well. From the current data he has Cities doesn't have to be an object at all, an array would be way simpler instead. And then you don't need the extra array to give an order to the properties.

Comment: That is true @user2415266 but I'm pretty sure that Gvkeyser is not iterating over an array. He starts by saying "I am looping through an object..."

Comment: I just edited my comment with a sentence which is basically the answer to your comment^^

Comment: Ahh, yes. I only just looked at the data that was actually in the object. You're absolutely right. An array would be a better tool to use than an object given the data in Cities object. I agree with @user2415266 iterating over an array with a for loop instead of a for...in loop is probably the best resolution.

Comment: Thanks Zac. Luckily my list won't update often if ever. I have tried using a for loop like so... for (var i=0; i < Cities.length; i++) {urls.push(url + Cities[i]}. Could you give an example how to inclued an array of strings of the keys in the object?

Comment: And when I used the for loop I had Cities = ['winhoek', 'graaff-reinet' ...bla bla]

Comment: And that didn't work Gvkeyser? There is an example in the answer already how to add an array of the object keys in the object to loop through them in order.

Comment: Then the problem might be in your Jade code - there you use "for each, i in Listings" - is that in arbitrary order as well maybe?

Comment: By the way guys Thank you for the super quick response. Zac I am going to give that a try.

Comment: Thats why I added it. I know nothing about jade and though that maybe the order gets shuffled there. Or maybe when the urls = [] array is build?

Comment: console.log your urls array it should be in order if you use the normal for loop. I have no idea about jade myself I'm using node with plain html and generate my data tables client side with javascript and ajax calls.

Comment: It is in order. I am going to make it a for loop with array just to neaten it up and then start to figure out how to make jade keep the order.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem...which creates a new problem. But I can live with the new problem. A piece of the code that I did not post in my original question is...

```
var numberOfParallelRequests = 20;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfParallelRequests; i++) {
      wizard();
    }
```

And that is the problem. It makes 20 requests at the same time in any order. If I make it 1 then it goes through the list one by one. The new problem is now it is very slow.